# Container element inside of a table that holds rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, html-table

I am dynamically inserting a table row (or multiple rows) into a table upon an ajax call's return. I am looking to accomplish this by having an empty container type element inside of my html table that I can insert `<tr>` elements into. As I have seen from other posts, a div cannot hold a tr element, so my question is, is there a particular way that I can insert the html for row(s) into a table? It must be dynamic in nature, or in other words I need to be able to hold more than just one `<tr>`.

Comment: What's wrong with `<table><tbody></tbody></table>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append to last row of table.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>First Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Middle Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Last Row</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
$( "#tableid tr:last" ).append(
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var row = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
```

You can then insert cells using `insertCell` on `row`.

Alternatively, if you have jQuery,

```
$("#myTable").append("<tr><td>Table Row with cell!</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use the `<table>` element directly, but you can use `<tbody>` elements as row containers within a table.

```js
onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("aButton").onclick = addRow.bind(null, "a");
  document.getElementById("bButton").onclick = addRow.bind(null, "b");
}

function addRow(id) {
  var r = document.getElementById(id).insertRow(-1);
  var c = r.insertCell(-1);
  c.innerHTML = "Row added at " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

```html
<button id="aButton">Add row to 'A'</button>
<button id="bButton">Add row to 'B'</button>
<table>
  <tbody><tr><td>Before A</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id="a"></tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>After A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Before B</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="b"></tbody>
  <tbody><tr><td>After B</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```